# SSAS Tabular: Append two tables with a different number of columns

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I'd like to ´UNION´ or ´Append´ two tables in SSAS with certain overlapping Column names, and some differences as well, which changes over time.

```
TableA:
| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | 1    | 0    | 1    |
| 0    | 1    | 1    | 1    |

TableB:
| ColA | ColB | ColE |
|------|------|------|
| 1    | 1    | 0    |
| 0    | 1    | 1    |

Expected Result:
| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE |
|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | 1    | 0    | 1    |      |
| 0    | 1    | 1    | 1    |      |
| 1    | 1    |      |      | 0    |
| 0    | 1    |      |      | 1    |
```

Is there an option in SSAS to make this happen?

Kind regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the Append function in Power Query. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries

In M, it is a `Table.Combine`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-combine